# Drupal 7 views Contextual filters with Blocks, default value doesn't work properly , wield

Tags: drupal, view

I have a view created that show content based on the url: eg: domain.com/projects/[username]/[projectname], which shows a project of a specific user, that works well. Additionally, I want to show the related projects of this user on the sidebar, so I create a block view, using the Contextual filters and the default value.

because my url is projects/username ,By using the default value -> raw value from URL, so I set the path component as 2. but that doesn't work for me.

eg: suppose my username is "abc".

in the preview, if the url path is "projects/abc", it doesn't show anything although the username is in the 2ed component of url path.

if the url path is "abc/*", it will show the related content, meaning as long as the username is in the first argument of the url path, it works.

I don't what happens, it seems that configuration of path component as 2 doesn't work. I am so puzzled , what happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo are missed something. I think each of your users have a url alias. For example 'user/1' have url alias 'abc'. Url components of contextual filter works for direct url, not for alias. For example second component of user url 'abc' will be '1', becauser original url is 'user/1'.
You can easily debug it by printing argument in working views header, try it yourself:

```
<?php print arg(0) . '<br>' . arg(1); ?>
```

For my user/1 that have alias 'abc' i received next:
user
1
For path  'abc/*' this is second component, but
 
for path 'projects/username' it is not 3-rd because this url hasn't aliases with [uid] component, you must use projects/[uid] or other validation for argument, for example you can check autor of a project. Choose a 'User ID from UR'L and check option 'Also look for a node and use the node author' in default value settings of contextual filter.